# Create Javascript object from HMTL table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like

```
    <table id="misc_inputs">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Property</th><th>Input</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td> 
                <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>b</td> 
                <td><input type="number" value="2"></td>
            </tr>
       ...
```

I would like to convert that table to a Javascript object like

```
misc_inputs = {"a": 1, "b": 2, ...
```

How can the result be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each inputs and create the object:

```js
var misc_inputs = {};
$("#misc_inputs input[type=number]").each(function(i, el){  
  var k = $(this).closest('td').prev().text();
  return misc_inputs[k] = +el.value;
});

console.log(misc_inputs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="misc_inputs">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Property</th><th>Input</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td> 
        <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td> 
        <td><input type="number" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below re-usable javascript method to convert any HTML table into Javascript object.

```
<table id="MyTable">
<thead>
    <tr><th>Property</th><th>Input</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="2"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    
    function ConvertHTMLToJSObject(htmlTableId)
    {
        var objArr = {};
        var trList = $('#' + htmlTableId).find('tr');
        $('#' + htmlTableId).find('tbody tr').each(function ()
        {
            var row = $(this);
            var key = $(row).first().text().trim();
            var value = $(row).find('input').attr("value");
            objArr[key] = value;
        });

        return objArr;
    }

    var obj = ConvertHTMLToJSObject("MyTable");
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do it without any library but with jQuery it's easier. Something like that should work (not tested):

```js
// Here we will store the results
var result = {};
// Ask jQuery to find each row (TR tag) and call a function for each
$('tr').each(function(){
    // Inside a jQuery each() "this" is the current element, the TR tag in this example
    var row = $(this);
    // We ask jQuery to find every TD inside the current row (the second parameter of a jQuery selector is the parent node for your search). We take the first one and then we take the content of the tag
    var label = $("td", row).first().text();
    // We ask for an "input" tag inside the current row and we read its "value" attribute
    var value = $("input", row).attr("value");
    // Store everything in result
    result[label] = value;
});
```

Comment: This seems very much in the right direction. I still haven't quite got it to work, so I have not yet accepted your answer, I'm working with your code here.

Comment: I've added some comments to explain what the snippet does